# Neo4J: Automatic Indexing on Batch Execution

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop

Is it possible to import data on Neo4J using the automatic indexing feature? I'm trying to import data using BatchInserter and BatchInserterIndex like the following example:

```
BatchInserter inserter = BatchInserters.inserter("/home/fmagalhaes/Neo4JDatabase");
BatchInserterIndexProvider indexProvider = new LuceneBatchInserterIndexProvider(inserter);
BatchInserterIndex nodeIndex = indexProvider.nodeIndex("node_auto_index", MapUtil.stringMap("type","exact"));
BatchInserterIndex relIndex = indexProvider.relationshipIndex("relationship_auto_index", MapUtil.stringMap("type","exact"));
...
inserter.createNode(vertexId, properties);
nodeIndex.add(vertexId, properties);
...
```

The problem is that when batch processing is completed, I'm trying to open this database with Blueprints generic API by doing the following:

```
Graph g = new Neo4jGraph("/home/fmagalhaes/Neo4JDatabase");
Set<String> nodeIndices = ((KeyIndexableGraph)g).getIndexedKeys(Vertex.class);
Set<String> relIndices = ((KeyIndexableGraph)g).getIndexedKeys(Edge.class);
```

and both nodeIndices and relIndices are empty. Auto indexing feature is disabled when I open the graph database on Blueprints API. Is it possible to create an automatic index during the batch processing such that this index will be visible (and will continue to index data automatically as properties are added to vertices and edges) when I open the database with Blueprints API?

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to cleanly shut down both the batch-index as well as the batch inserter
2. you probably don't want to index all properties, just the key ones that you use to look up nodes
3. you have to enable auto-indexing in the neo4j config for the database you start afterwards, and for the same properties that you indexed during batch-insertion

Comment: 1. I've ommited in the example above but I'm shutting down both IndexProvider and BatchInserter.
2. Correct. In fact I'm testing Blueprints and Neo4J and the only property that I'm using is: "__id". I want to index this property because I want to use IdGraph wrapper from Blueprints API.
3. How can I enable auto index on an embedded Neo4j database? Should I use node_auto_indexing=true and relationship_auto_indexing=true configurations when opening the database?

Comment: Also, when I import my data using only the Blueprints API (and Neo4jGraph class implementation) instead of using BatchInserts, when I use createKeyIndex() method, I'm able to open the database at a later point directly without the need of setting node_auto_indexing=true and relationship_auto_indexing=true. Somehow this configuration is embedded on the database itself. Is it possible to embbed this auto_index behavior on the database when using BathInserts instead of having to set them manually on the configurations when I open the database?